# simply polar elements in a ring

Tags: ring-theory, banach-algebras

An element $a$  in a ring $A$ with identity is said to be simply polar if there is $b$ for which  $a=aba$, with $ab=ba$. 
If in addition $b=bab$ then such an element $b$ is unique. 
The question is why $b$ commutes with everything that commutes with $a$.

Comment: Note that $a=0$ is polar with arbitrary $b$. While $0$ commutes with everything, this need not be the case with every $b$. So is the question really aimed *only* at the cases where $b$ is unique (or where $b$ is also witnessed as polar by $a$)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen While $0=0b0$ for nonzero $b$, the other requirement $b=b0b$ won't work out.

Comment: the question really aimed only at the cases where b is unique

Comment: @rschwieb OK, I thought the problem formulation was not clear whether "If $P$ then $Q$" was just trivia ror should read "Additionally assume $P$, which is known to imply $Q$".

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I agree it's not very clear!

Answer (score 1):

Assume $ac=ca$.
Then $abca=abac=ac=ca=caba=acba$, hence
$abc=bac=bca = babca=bacba=abcab = acbab=acb$, i.e. $bc-cb$ is left annihilated by $a$ (and by symmetry  is also right annihilated).
Then 
$a(bc-cb+b)a = aba=a$ and $a(bc-cb+b) = ab=ba = (bc-cb+b)a$ and the uniqueness of $b$ implies $bc-cb+b=b$ and finally $bc=cb$.

Comment: why bc−cb is right annihilated